# Modifying the walker to insert parent's description above sub menus

Tags: menus, walker

I would like to show the title or the description of the parent item on top of the the sub-menu list items. I have basic knowledge on how to modify the walker by calling start_lvl function to insert after `<u>` or start_el to insert after `<li>` but couldn't pull the "item->Description" of the parent item to concentrate into the $output var.

such as

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="">German Cars</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="">BMW</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Mercedes</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Volkswagen</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="">American Cars</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="">Chrysler</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Ford</a></li>
         <li><a href="">General Motors</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

to show like

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="">German Cars</a>
      <ul>
         <h2>Cars Made in Germany </h2> <!--parent list item's description shows here-->
         <li><a href="">BMW</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Mercedes</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Volkswagen</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="">American Cars</a>
      <ul>
         <h2>Cars Made in the USA</h2> <!--parent list item's description shows here-->
         <li><a href="">Chrysler</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Ford</a></li>
         <li><a href="">General Motors</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Could anybody please guide me here..?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, the first thing you would need to do is, go to your menus /wp-admin/nav-menus.php (screen options) and checkbox (tick) on the description.
and this is how your walker class should look like

```
    class Menu_With_Description extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '<br /><span class="sub">' . $item->description . '</span>';
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

and than locate your wp_nav_menu and update it with

```
    <?php $walker = new Menu_With_Description; ?>

<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'walker' => $walker ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will apply this code; but before i will try understand how it works..

Comment: I don't think this solution is correct. The requested header must be inserted by the start_lvl method however we must also utilize the start_el methode just for the sake of passing the $items->description to start_lvl method via a public var.

Comment: did u got any error while using the code ? as i am using this same code on one of client sites and it works perfectly